# How to add properly to TypeScript a callback type with parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this method:

```
export default class ApiService {
  static makeApiCall = (
    url: string,
    normalizeCallback: (d: ResponseData) => ResponseData | null,
    callback: (d: any) => any
  ): Promise<void> => (
    ApiClient.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        callback(normalizeCallback(res.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(`ApiClient ${url}`, error);
      })
  )

  static getArticles = (callback: (a: Article[]) => void): Promise<void> => (
    ApiService.makeApiCall(
      'articles',
      ApiNormalizer.normalizeArticles,
      callback
    )
  )
}
```

On this line `callback: (d: any) => any` typescript yells

> warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type

To show you more context, here is where I am calling the method `getArticles`

```
export const fetchArticles = (): ThunkAction<Promise<void>,{},{},AnyAction> => {
  return async (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>): Promise<void> => {
    dispatch(() => ({ type: FETCH_ARTICLES }));
             // HERE: getArticles
    return ApiService.getArticles(articles => dispatch(loadArticles(articles)));
  };
};
```

So how can i type that callback function properly?

Comment: Well what *is* it going to get and receive? It looks like it gets the result of normalizeCallback and returns void, based on its usage and the overall signature.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe I placed the whole method with its calls and how it is used. It receives arrays and objects as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write it as:

```
function makeApi<T>(url: string, normalizeCallback: (d: ResponseData) => T | null) {
  return function(callback: (data: T | null) => any) {
    return ApiClient.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        callback(normalizeCallback(res.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(`ApiClient ${url}`, error);
      });
  };
}

// in the class
static getArticles = makeApi<Article[]>("articles", ApiNormalizer.normalizeArticles)
```

That way, you ...

1) correctly type the data type as a generic.

2) eliminate a lot of boilerplate.

3) enclose `makeApi` into the module, I don't think it should be exposed through the class.

Comment: Where `T` comes from?

Comment: First, on `function` declaration: `Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)` then on `callback(normalizeCallback(res.data));` => `Argument of type 'T | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.`

Comment: Ah, the second was a wrong type. I think you should be able to resplve the first one on your own if you reread the answer ...